# deleteing data from sqlite and tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I am trying to delete data from the sqlite .data I'll deleting from bottom to top approach but randomly deleting data the data was swiping from one row details to other row please help me to delete data.

This is my code

appdelegate.m

```
-(void)deleteData:(NSString *)str:(NSString *)string
{   
    NSLog(@"intIndexpath:--> %d",intIndexpath);

    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

    sqlite3_stmt *deleteStatement = nil;

    NSString *sql;

    int returnvalue;

    sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM UserInfo_1 WHERE rowid=%d",intIndexpath+1];

    returnvalue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &deleteStatement, NULL);

    if (returnvalue == 1)
    {
        NSAssert1 (0,@"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(deleteStatement, 1,[strAcountName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if (SQLITE_DONE!= sqlite3_step(deleteStatement))
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleteing data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    if (sqlite3_prepare(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &deleteStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" message:@"Record Deleted" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];   
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        alert=nil;

    }
    else
        sqlite3_reset(deleteStatement);

    sqlite3_finalize(deleteStatement);
    deleteStatement = NULL;
}
```

tableview.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        apd.intIndexpath = indexPath.row;

        [apd deleteData:[apd.ArrAcName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] :apd.strAcountName];
        [apd.ArrAcName removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        apd =(PasswordAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

//        NSLog(@"apd.strAcountName is:--> %@",apd.strAcountName);

        // [apd deleteData:apd.strAcountName];

        self.navigationItem.title =@"Details";

        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: define     apd = (PasswordAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; above apd.intIndexpath = ... that line then only [apd deleteData] fn will be called

Comment: thank u for replay actually i am delete record randomly then i get problem ,i am deleting record based on rowid in database but rowid is not update dynamically that means example my table rowid values is 1,2,3,4 if delete rowid = 3 database rowid values is 1,2,4 but i need rowid values is 1,2,3 after deleteing rowid = 3 also ..is it possible ??????? please post what query for update rowid dynamically after deleteing record randomly ???

Comment: Yes, when you read the data to populate the `UITableView`, you should save the respective `rowid` values (or, better, the primary key) in something like a `NSMutableArray` and then look that up when you go to delete the row.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of reactions:

1. It looks like you are using `rowid` as if it was a row number. It's not. It's a unique row identifier that doesn't change for a given row regardless of whether you add or delete other rows. So, if you have five rows (with `rowid` running from 1 to 5), and delete the first one, then the `rowid` for the subsequent four records doesn't change (they'll remain 2, 3, 4, and 5 after you delete the row with the `rowid` of 1). If you have records "randomly" deleting, I'm wondering if you're grabbing the `row` number from your `indexPath` and assuming that that will correspond to table `rowid` values, which it won't after you've deleted a single record from the table.

   What you want to do is that as you read the data from the database, also read and save the respective `rowid`, too (or better, if your table has a primary key, use that). Then, when go to delete a row, you should not just be using a `rowid` equal to your `indexPath.row`, but rather you should be grabbing the unique `rowid` (or primary key) you saved at the beginning that corresponds to the current `indexPath.row` to figure out how to delete the row in question.
2. Unrelated, but it doesn't seem that you need to be doing any `sqlite3_bind`. You don't appear to have any parameters that need binding.
3. Also unrelated, but after your `sqlite3_step`, you're then doing another `sqlite3_prepare`, which doesn't make sense. If `sqlite3_step` succeeded, you can just `sqlite3_finalize` and quit.
4. As an aside, you might want to contemplate using an Objective-C wrapper, such as the excellent [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/). It really simplifies the SQLite programming process.